# O uso das preposições "com" e "de" no relatório radiológico: Fígado "com" [ou] "de" dimensões aumentadas?

Tags: preposições

## Contexto

Em um relatório radiológico é necessário *descrever os órgãos* com suas características normais ou alteradas. Na prática é muito frequente o *uso das preposições "com" e "de" de modo equivalente*, como no exemplo:

> Fígado **com** dimensões aumentadas.
>
> Fígado **de** dimensões aumentadas.

## Pergunta

Estão corretos ambos os usos?

O objetivo do relatório é *caracterizar o órgão em questão* (no exemplo, o fígado). É possível que o valor semântico das preposições não seja exatamente o mesmo.

Se entrevistássemos um casal, candidatos a modelos fotográficos, em geral anotaríamos "Esposa *com* pernas compridas" ou "Esposa é uma mulher *de* pernas compridas". Creio que anotar "Esposa de pernas compridas" não seja incorreto, mas me soaria estranho ao ler a anotação, como me soa estranho quando leio "Fígado **de** dimensões aumentadas".

Seria apenas uma questão de estilo? Ou a preposição "de" teria um sentido mais genérico, enquanto "com" um sentido mais estrito?

## Referências

De acordo com o [Dicionário Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=com), a preposição "com" pode estabelecer relação que expressa *característica*:

> 10 Partícula que estabelece relação de dependência, que expressa algo caracterizado por: Há várias candidatas, mas o chefe precisa de uma secretária com iniciativa.

De modo semelhante, segundo o [Dicionário de Português da Oxford](https://www.google.com/search?q=definicao+de), a preposição "de" também poderia ligar atribuindo "característica":

> 2 ligando dois substantivos (ou equivalentes), diretamente ou com auxílio de verbos de ligação, adquire os sentidos:
>
> (...)
>
> 2.8 característica genérica ou particular < pessoa de respeito > | < homem de nariz grande >

Comment: Pois, há muitas situações em *com* e *de* servem (homem de/com chapéu aos quadradinhos). O que me deixa um pouco na dúvida é o *dimensões aumentadas*. Isso é linguagem técnica? Significa que está maior que da última vez que foi observado?

Comment: @Jacinto _Dimensões aumentadas_ significa que está maior do que o valor de referência. Para o fígado, geralmente usamos 16 cm como limite máximo para o lobo direito; portanto, na prática, dizemos que o fígado está “com dimensões aumentadas” quando a medida do lobo direito é maior que 16 cm.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que o uso do "de" remete (mais que "com") a uma *classe*, *tipo*. Por isso inclusive lhe pareceria mais natural "mulher de perna comprida" do que "esposa de perna comprida": classificar esposas é ainda mais estranho que classificar mulheres dessa forma.

Então eu diria que as duas opções, "fígado com/de dimensões aumentadas", são equivalentes no sentido de conterem a mesma informação no contexto, mas a com "com" estaria mais próxima de "está maior", enquanto a com "de", de "é maior".

Mas esta é só minha impressão no momento - a diferença, se existir, é muito leve e subjetiva, espero que alguém ofereça uma reposta melhor embasada.

Comment: Também é para aí que eu me inclino.